# CSS Conflict

Tags: css, focus

Im trying to do a simple :focus effect for all my INPUT elements, like so:

```
INPUT:focus { border-color: orange; }
```

This works great, until I add this bit of CSS to the style sheet:

```
.form_container .col2 INPUT
{
border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
font-family:arial; 
font-size:14px;
padding:3px;
}
```

Now once  I add the above, the focus effect doesnt work on any input within the form_container class, when I take the above out it works.

I can get the effect to work by specifying the class for the INPUT like so:

```
.form_container .col2 INPUT:focus { border-color: orange; }
```

But I dont understand why I have to do this? I want to control all INPUT effects like  i do in the first example

if any one can shed some light on this 
thx

Answer (score 7):

That's because

**`.form_container .col2 INPUT`**

is more *specific* than

**`INPUT:focus`**

In CSS, more specific rules have higher priority, no matter what the order is in which they were declared. Rules that are equally specific (*the same number of selectors usuall*y), the rule declared later overrides or adds to rule declared first.

You could specify **!important** on your border style for the second rule, but it's not supported in all browsers (did I hear IE?)

Comment: It might be worth adding -if only for the sake of completion- that if any two rules are equally specific, the later-declared rule wins out.

Comment: actually IE does support !important... maybe not IEs down the line (namely <IE6) but WHO CARES... STOP SUPPORTING <IE6! IT MUST DIE

Answer (score 1):

In your first rule you're declaring the border color. In your second rule you're overriding it. You could try something like

```
INPUT:focus { border-color: orange!important; }
```